# Constructing a URL from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an Array:

```
var arr[];
```

I have inserted many coordinates to this (`x` and `y` values)

```
arr[0]=12+'#'+32;
arr[1]=34+'#'+87;
arr[2]=90+'#'+89;
```

So when i print this array i get a string like `,12#32,34#87,90#89`. These are coordinates. How do i break these and append this to a string which will be in the format.

`http://host/app?x1=12&y1=32&x2=32&y2=87&x3=90&y3=89`

This above URL can have many parameters. How can i construct the above URL from my array.

Comment: How is the array being constructed?

Comment: Just loop through it and split the values. While doing that append all those items to an array and join when you are done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build your querystring looping through the array (here I used [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)) and using the [`.split()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) function to separate your coordinates.

```
var qs;
$.each(arr,function(i,v){
  qs += "x" + i + "=" + v.split("#")[0] + "&y" + i + "=" + v.split("#")[1] + ((i+1)!=arr.length) ? "&" : "";      
});

var url = "http://host/app?" + qs;
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the above answers, loop through, split on the hash, add the pieces to the query string, and append the ampersand if you're not at the end.

```
for(var c = 0, query = "http://host/app?", coordinate; c < arr.length; c++) {
  coordinate = arr[c].split("#");
  query += "x" + (c + 1) + "=" + coordinate[0] + "&";
  query += "y" + (c + 1) + "=" + coordinate[1];
  if(c < arr.length - 1) query += "&";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach I can think of is:

```
var arr = [12+'#'+32, 34+'#'+87, 90+'#'+89],
    url = 'http://host/app',
    params = [], temp;

arr.forEach(function (a) {
    temp = a.split('#');
    params.push('x=' + temp[0] + 'y=' + temp[1]);
});

url += params.join('&');

console.log(url);
```

```js
var arr = [12+'#'+32, 34+'#'+87, 90+'#'+89],
    url = 'http://host/app',
    params = [], temp;

arr.forEach(function (a) {
    temp = a.split('#');
    params.push('x=' + temp[0] + 'y=' + temp[1]);
});

url += params.join('&');

console.log(url);
```

References:

- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
- [`Array.prototype.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).
- [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split/).